# What is sigaddset used for?

Tags: c, linux, signals, posix, alarm

I have this code where I use sigaddset and sigaction. However if I comment segaddset the result is the same

```
   struct sigaction act; 

   act.sa_handler = process_alarm; 
   act.sa_flags = 0;           
   sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask); 
   //sigaddset(&act.sa_mask, SIGINT); 

   sigaction(SIGALRM, &act, NULL);

   for(;;) 
   { 
      alarm(3); 
      pause();  
   }
```

Why do I need to use it?

Comment: did you try pressing `CTRL + C` when running your program with/ without commenting out `sigaddset()` ?

Comment: @SouravGhosh yes but as pointed in other answers i the alarm handler runs to quickly to notice its effect. Adding a `sleep(10)` in handler and i can see the difference :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are doing 2 things here:

1. Populating a `sigset_t`. A sigset_t is just a collection of values for signals, and are used in various system calls. You can:

   - Create an empty sigset_t (sigemptyset()
   - Add a signal to the set (sigaddset())
   - Remove a signal to the set (sigdelset())
   - etc...
2. Setting the signal mask for the signal handler. You do that by manipulating the `sigset_t sa_mask` member of the `struct sigaction` when you set up a signal handler in with a call to sigaction().

The signal mask of a signal handler means that while the signal handler is executing, the signals that are in the mask will be blocked - i.e. those signals will not be handled as long as they are blocked. When the signal handler are finished, the signals in will be unblocked.
A signal that is blocked isn't "lost", it will be handled when that particular signal is unblocked again.

The `sigaddset(&act.sa_mask, SIGINT);` means the the SIGINT signal cannot occur while the code for the `SIGALRM` handler is running.

On the other hand, if you comment out `sigaddset(&act.sa_mask, SIGINT);`, you're left with just an empty list of signals created with `sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);`. So any signals that occur while the SIGALRM handler function is running might preempt that handler and execute the signal handler for that other signal.

For a SIGINT, you would normally not notice any difference with manual testing - it's unlikely you manage to hit CTRL-C exactly when your handler for SIGALRM is running, and your SIGALRM handler probably runs quickly enough that you would not notice if the SIGINT was slightly delayed.

Answer (score 9):

Signals sets are manipulated via `sigset_t` type. Several operations are available for signals sets:

- create an empty set S via `sigemptyset`, S=∅
- add a signal s to a set S via `sigaddset`, S=S∪{s}
- remove a signal s from a set via `sigdelset`, S=S\{s}
- create the set of all possible signals via `sigfillset`.
- test is a signal s is in a given set S via `sigismember`, s∈S?

Such a set is used at different places: setting a new process signal mask, blocking set during signal handling, requesting the set of pending signals, etc.

If you want to catch different signals, it may appears that some catching functions must not be interrupted with others, so you can add a set of signals to be blocked during the delivery of a given signal. You actually  decided (when uncommented) to block SIGINT during SIGALRM delivery. So you can only observe this by sending a SIGINT during the execution of the handler; which is difficult to realize.

A example where it can be important ?

Suppose that the handler of SIGUSR1 modify a given data structure and that the handler for SIGUSR2 uses that same data structure. It is very important to make both handlers not concurrent, one can be run after the other but you probably don't want to be interrupted by one during the delivery of the other. Your code is *self-concurrent*, say that even in the case of only one thread, signals can lead you to concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

sigaddset is used for adding the corresponding signal mask to that sigset_t variable.

In sigaction, it is not required. You can use that when you are using the sigprocmask which is for blocking the signal which we mentioning in that variable.